# How to sum array value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have `2` array variable I want to sum array and divide into two parts. Please look my code -

```
print_r($public);
```

output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 32
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 20
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 7
    [15] => 0
    [16] => 0
    [17] => 0
    [18] => 0
    [19] => 0
    [20] => 0
    [21] => 0
    [22] => 0
    [23] => 0
    [24] => 0
    [25] => 0
    [26] => 11
    [27] => 0
    [28] => 0
    [29] => 0
    [30] => 0
)



print_r($private);

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 7
    [15] => 0
    [16] => 0
    [17] => 0
    [18] => 0
    [19] => 0
    [20] => 0
    [21] => 0
    [22] => 4
    [23] => 0
    [24] => 0
    [25] => 0
    [26] => 0
    [27] => 0
    [28] => 2
    [29] => 0
    [30] => 0
)
```

My Output should be -

```
$variable1=array_sum($public) + array_sum($private); //for First 15 days(array)
$variable2 = array_sum($public) + array_sum($private); //For 16 to end of the array
```

`$public` and `$private` is two array. contans `May` month date wise records. I want to sum array value into two divide parts.

> 1st -  Day - 1-15(sum of array 0 to 14)
>
> 2nd - Day - 16-end of month(sum of array 15 to end of the array)

How to calculate both variable into two divide parts in a single line code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
 $first_part = array_sum(array_slice($public, 0, 15));
 $second_part = array_sum(array_slice($public, 15, 16));
```

---

```
 $first_part = array_sum(array_slice($public, 0, 15)) + array_sum(array_slice($private, 0, 15));
 $second_part = array_sum(array_slice($public, 15, 16)) + array_sum(array_slice($private, 15, 16));
```

Comment: You have entered `16`. Tell me why I will entering `16` The last digit may be 28, 29, 30 or 31

Comment: You are only calculate `$public` variable. I want to sum both `$public` and `$private` variable

Comment: `array_slice` will attempt to get `16` items, if there are less items it will return less. `16` because `15+16 = 31` which is the maximum number of days in a month.

Comment: If you want to sum both `$public` and `$private` sum them separately and add them together: `$first_part_public + $first_part_private`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your comment. But I also sum both variable. Please check I have edited my question.

Comment: Exactly. I want to add together.